# Context MKIV \cite stopped processing \righttext

Tags: bibliographies, context

Context MKIV worked with `\cite[righttext={}][key]` perfectly, then stopped. Where to look for problems?

MWE

```
\usebtxdataset[default][bib.bib]
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]
\setupbtxrendering[default][numbering=yes]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\definebtxrendering[example][aps][specification=apa,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]
\setupindenting[big,yes]

\starttext

\startbodymatter

\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
\startchapter[title=Bibliography]
\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]
\stopchapter
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the issue that it “works perfectly, then stopped”.

```
\startbuffer[bib]
@article{PhysRevLett.107.116801,
  title = {Geometrical Description of the Fractional Quantum Hall Effect},
  author = {Haldane, F. D. M.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {107},
  issue = {11},
  pages = {116801},
  numpages = {5},
  year = {2011},
  month = {Sep},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.116801},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.116801}
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[default][bib.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]

\starttext

\cite[righttext={}][PhysRevLett.107.116801]
\cite[righttext={hello world}][PhysRevLett.107.116801]

\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your variant works, mine does not even after full reinstall (of Context). Must be a local bug or a dataset definition (apa, chicago) inconsistency.